# How to make JSONObject ignore special meaning for 'null' and print it as literal null

Tags: java, json

I am using `net.sf.json.JSONObject`

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("id", "null");
System.out.println(obj.toString());
```

The output is

```
{"id":null}
```

I want null to be quoted in the output as literal `"null"`

```
{"id":"null"}
```

Since `null, true, false` are keywords that is how `JSONObject` treats it when converting it to string.  I tried 
`obj.put("id", "\"null\"");` - still the same result

We have some legacy code that will flow in easily if I can get it to print `null` as a literal than make it json `null`.

Any help?

Comment: No the JSONObject code seems to be checking for both " and '

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a bug with the implementation of the JSON library you are using.

An easy solution would be to switch to a JSON library that is actually working.

I am using these 2 JSON libraries which I would recommend to you:

1. [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)
2. [json-smart](http://code.google.com/p/json-smart/)

Both of these libraries work as required by your implementation with a String "null" value. I tested both with sample code:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("test", "null");

// Both libraries print out {"test":"null"}
System.out.println(obj.toJSONString());
```

Answer (score -2):

Use JsonWriter class method WriteNull.

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx

Comment: you provided a .NET answer but the question is about a Java library.